# NeoVim JDTLS configuration

Tags: java, neovim, neovim-plugin, nvim-lspconfig

for my many tries to configure JDTLS (in past I do it and it work very well) I can't do that. Something weird I observed that java standard packages (java.util.*, java.lang.* etc) aren't indexed. What can be a problem? [LSP outoup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cJ37.png)

I used standard nvim-jdtls config:

```lua
local config = {
    cmd = {'/path/to/jdt-language-server/bin/jdtls'},
    root_dir = vim.fs.dirname(vim.fs.find({'gradlew', '.git', 'mvnw'}, { upward = true })[1]),
}
require('jdtls').start_or_attach(config)
```

I tried Coc-jdtls, my own jdtls config, nvim-jdtls, java-language-server and every time problem is the same: standard java packages aren't indexed.